# row no-gutters not removing spacing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not really sure why, but `<div class="row no-gutters` isn't removing empty spaces.

There's a big space between the buttons in the grid. I removed every id and class to ensure nothing is messing with margins or padding, but issue still persists. Any ideas?

```
<div class="row no-gutters">

  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div [@simpleFadeAnimation]="'in'">
      <button mat-raised-button (click)="auctionEndingSoonestFilter()"
        [ngClass]="[this.auctionEndingSoonestStatus ? 'enabled' : 'disabled']" *ngIf="!isLoading && this.posts.length >0">
        <mat-icon>access_time</mat-icon>&nbsp;Auctions Ending Soonest
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div [@simpleFadeAnimation]="'in'">
      <button  mat-raised-button (click)="buyItNowFilter()"
        [ngClass]="[this.buyItNowStatus ? 'enabled' : 'disabled']" *ngIf="!isLoading && this.posts.length >0">
        <mat-icon>attach_money</mat-icon>Buy It Now Only
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
      <div [@simpleFadeAnimation]="'in'">
        <button mat-raised-button (click)="buyItNowFilter()"
          [ngClass]="[this.buyItNowStatus ? 'enabled' : 'disabled']" *ngIf="!isLoading && this.posts.length >0">
          <mat-icon>remove_red_eye</mat-icon>Private Auctions Only
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap grid is based on `flexbox` so it divides the row width on the number of its columns.

`no-gutters` removes margins from rows and padding from columns and won't affect the width of columns.

Try using `col-md-auto` instead for the columns.